# Unable to download .jar files inside m2 repository using maven dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2, m2eclipse

This is the error thrown,

> Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0 from
>   http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update   interval of
>   ibiblio.org has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could
>   not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0 from/to
>   ibiblio.org (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/  maven2): Access denied to
>   http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar.
>   Error code 403, Forbidden

In Pic,

[image]

---

I have the same issue in two different machines [One of the machines with Proxy and other without proxy (Personnel laptop)]

I'm using

> 1. Eclipse Kepler
> 2. JDK 1.6
> 3. Maven 3.0.4

No luck after lots of attempts; Some of them are listed below:

- downgraded **JDK [Java]** from `1.7` to `1.6`
- added proxy on `settings.xml` under [`C:\Users\prashanth_sams\.m2`]

  [image]
- added mirror in `settings.xml` under `C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml`

[image]

- located specific Maven version location externally

[image]

But, instead of jar files, I see the following two files present inside the repo with suffix, `.lastUpdated`

Is there any other mirrors to be added in the settings.xml? Any help is highly welcome!

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using Maven Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)?

Comment: Thanks Carl, Finally I did that on settings.xml <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>

Comment: @PrashanthSams : can you please share settings.xml file prashant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue got fixed when I add the mirrors on **settings.xml** which is located in `C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml` from the below URL

> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.meta/repository-metadata.xml

After updating the XML, try `Maven > Update Project..`